# What exactly am I supposed to do for OAuth 2.0 and https update?

Tags: facebook, oauth

I am a php developer. I created an application using fbml(non iframe) and didn't check roadmap regularly.
Today I received an email saying update to OAuth 2.0 and HTTPS by October 1st or the apps may be disabled.
I went through the documentation but could not get what exactly I am supposed to do.

From what I understood.
for https
we need to enable or buy ssl for our site and make https://example.com/facebookapps_folder/ accessible and fill the new url in Secure Canvas URL
Is that right?

I am confused about OAuth 2.0.For this do we need to change the whole code and libraries we are referring to.
Where can I get how do I change it.
I see some php examples but could not find clue what needs to be changed?
I think it is way authentication is being done, but I do I do that.

If I fail to do it immediately(as only 3 days left) is that any way I can save my application being disabled?

Comment: This is what you need to change. [Take a look here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/). It is a PHP tutorial from Naitik

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have implemented Oauth2.0 for authentication .. Also you will need an SSL certificate for your app to support https:// protocol